# BeagleBone Black & U-Boot 2020.07: fit_find_config_node: Missing FDT description in DTB

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

My environment is the following:

1. beaglebone black rev C
2. u-boot 2020.07 built using the defconfig (am335x_evm_defconfig)
3. kernel is loaded via TFTP
4. RFS is mounted via NFS (buildroot)

My beaglebone Black is giving me this error when attempting to boot from an uSD card:

```
U-Boot SPL 2020.07 (Sep 22 2020 - 16:58:58 -0700)                                                                                                    
Trying to boot from MMC1                                                                                                                             
fit_find_config_node: Missing FDT description in DTB                                                                                                 
No matching DT out of these options:
```

[image: BBB MLO Boot error]

When I boot w/o pressing the S2 button, it appears that the MLO in the eMMC is used which loads the uEnv.txt on the SD card.

I've created a bash script that automates formatting my SD card (i.e. creating a FAT16 partition using sfdisk & mkfs.vfat):

```
#! /bin/sh
#    
#
#Before running, first give 755 permissions:
# chmod 755 mk2partSDcard.sh

#To run script, provide the device (/dev/sdb, /dev/mmcblk) the SD card is 
#attached to using the following:
# 1. lsblk -l 
# 2. df -hT
#and pass the device to the script as root:
#sudo mk2partSDcard.sh /dev/sdb
     
#DRIVE=$1

#if [ ! -e $DRIVE ]
#then
#   echo "\"$DRIVE\" doesn't exist... closing"
#   exit -1
#fi 

#should only perform the following when re-using an already formatted sd 
#card. No need to do this on a brand new card.
#Erase partition table/labels on uSD card:
dd if=/dev/zero of=$DRIVE bs=1M count=10

#clear additional locations of previous MLOs
#dd if=/dev/zero of=$DRIVE bs=512 count=1 seek=512 
#dd if=/dev/zero of=$DRIVE bs=512 count=1 seek=768 

#type - 0x01=FAT12; 0x04=FAT16; 0x0b=W95 FAT32; 0x0c=W95 FAT32 (LBA); 
#0x0e=W95 FAT16 (LBA); 0x0f=W95 Ext'd (LBA)

#bootable - [ * | - ]

#echo "Starting sfdisk"
#sfdisk $DRIVE <<-__EOF__
#,4096,0x0e,*
#To add additional partition, uncomment the following:
#,+,83
#__EOF__

#echo "Starting mkfs"
#mkfs.vfat -c -F 16 -n "BOOT" -v ${DRIVE}1
#umount ${DRIVE}1
#mkfs.ext4 -L "\ROOTFS\" -O ^metadata_csum,^64bit -v ${DRIVE}2
#umount ${DRIVE}2
#echo "Done script"
```

I managed to track down `fit_find_config_node` to `common_fit.c` and I noticed this in the [u-boot readme (line # 52)](https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot/-/blob/v2020.07/common/common_fit.c):

```
 #include <common.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <image.h>
#include <log.h>
#include <linux/libfdt.h>

ulong fdt_getprop_u32(const void *fdt, int node, const char *prop)
{
    const u32 *cell;
    int len;

    cell = fdt_getprop(fdt, node, prop, &len);
    if (!cell || len != sizeof(*cell))
        return FDT_ERROR;

    return fdt32_to_cpu(*cell);
}

/*
 * Iterate over all /configurations subnodes and call a platform specific
 * function to find the matching configuration.
 * Returns the node offset or a negative error number.
 */
int fit_find_config_node(const void *fdt)
{
    const char *name;
    int conf, node, len;
    const char *dflt_conf_name;
    const char *dflt_conf_desc = NULL;
    int dflt_conf_node = -ENOENT;

    conf = fdt_path_offset(fdt, FIT_CONFS_PATH);
    if (conf < 0) {
        debug("%s: Cannot find /configurations node: %d\n", __func__,
              conf);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    dflt_conf_name = fdt_getprop(fdt, conf, "default", &len);

    for (node = fdt_first_subnode(fdt, conf);
         node >= 0;
         node = fdt_next_subnode(fdt, node)) {
        name = fdt_getprop(fdt, node, "description", &len);
        if (!name) {
#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_LIBCOMMON_SUPPORT
            printf("%s: Missing FDT description in DTB\n",
                   __func__);
#endif
            

    return -EINVAL;
            }
    
            if (dflt_conf_name) {
                const char *node_name = fdt_get_name(fdt, node, NULL);
                if (strcmp(dflt_conf_name, node_name) == 0) {
                    dflt_conf_node = node;
                    dflt_conf_desc = name;
                }
            }
    
            if (board_fit_config_name_match(name))
                continue;
    
            debug("Selecting config '%s'", name);
    
            return node;
        }
    
        if (dflt_conf_node != -ENOENT) {
            debug("Selecting default config '%s'\n", dflt_conf_desc);
            return dflt_conf_node;
        }
    
        return -ENOENT;
    }
```

Line 52 from `common_fit.c`:
[image: IFDEF_SPL_LIBCOMMON]

since that is enabled by the deconfig I don't want to change that.

My goal is to boot from and SD (like I was in the past) using the MLO, u-boot.img, & uEnV.txt. I'm not sure what has changed from before. I also have a hexdump of my SD card available upon request.

Comment: You should put text content formatted as code (double braces in the editor menu bar) instead of screen-shots: this would allow people who want to help to simply copy/paste the exact commands/code you have been experimenting with. This is not too late for doing it.

Comment: Please augment your question with all messages that were displayed by u-boot from the time the beaglebone was powered on, more specifically the command that was used for booting linux: it should specify the dtb file you should have retrieved using TFTP.

Comment: Something is wrong with the FIT image that you are using with SPL. We are close to releasing U-Boot v2020.10. Please, rebuild with git HEAD. If v2020.10-rc5 has the same problem, please, contact the maintainer. See board/ti/beagle/MAINTAINERS

Comment: @Frant done, I appreciate your feedback

Comment: @Xypron will do thanks

Comment: @Niko_Jako from the new information you provided, I would folllow Xypron's trail.